# AWS DMS - Source S3, Target Aurora MySQL- Error- invalid utf8mb4 character string

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

My source is CSV files in S3 bucket and destination is Aurora MySQL 5.7.

The database is defined with charset utf8 and the table also uses utf8.

My source file is using latin1 (iso-8859-1) charset has special characters like ¢ and ° .

I am getting invalid utf8mb4 character string error every time I try to load the file.

I tried to find any option that I can use as a workaround in DMS however I cannot.

I am able to load the file w/o DMS by using LOAD DATA FROM S3 command with 'USING CHARSET latin1' option however I don't see any such option in DMS.

I understand that the LOAD DATA INFILE command in MySQL interprets the file contents using the character set indicated by the *character_set_database* system variable. Assuming DMS is referring to the same, just to validate the theory I also changed the charset of DB to *latin1* which essentially changes the variable *character_set_database*.  I also changed the table to *latin1*. None of this helped :(

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - I opened a ticket with AWS support who confirmed that DMS only supports UTF-8 file format as of today.

Given the issue I faced they have opened a feature request for DMS to support other formats when target is MySQL. Of course there is no ETA for this.

In the meantime, we can convert the file to utf-8 first and then load them via DMS. Conversion can be done using `iconv` command.